# How can I change request url by every each loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cheerio, node-request

I'm trying to get a src of each video from links from post param using `request` and `cheerio`.

To get a src of each video, I should change the url of request option by every loop. but when I try to get a src like code below, changing url of request is faster than request, so changing the url of request is done before the request is done. What can I do to implement what I want?

Here's code

```
let opt = {
    transform: function(body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
    }
};

router.post('/api', function(req, res) {
    let idArray = req.body.data;
    for(var i=0; i<idArray.length; i++) {
        opt.uri = baseURL + idArray[i];

        request(opt)
          .then(function($)  {
               console.log($('video').src);
           }
```

Log (**It prints same thing**)

`https://example.mp4/asdfasdf
https://example.mp4/asdfasdf`

**EDIT**

when I use this code, I get undefined from idArray[i]

```
for(var i=0; i<idArray.length; i++) {
        console.log("Before", baseURL + idArray[i])
        rpap(baseURL + idArray[i])
          .then(function($) {
              console.log(idArray);
              console.log("After", baseURL + idArray[i]);
}
```

log

```
before http://example.com/adsfasdf
 before http://example.com/famvvasd
 after  http://example.com/undefined
 after  http://example.com/undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just merge your new uri with the global options object? I'd advice against changing the global options object as multiple requests can be made and the prop can be changed in unexpected ways.

```
for (var i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
  let uri = baseURL + idArray[i];

  request({
      ...opt,
      uri // expands to uri: uri as per es6 style
    })
    .then(function($) {
      console.log($('video').src);
    })
}
```

Also, if you always use the transform option then you could set it as default. With request-promise it would look something like this (from their docs):

```
var rpap = rp.defaults({ transform: autoParse });

rpap('http://google.com')
    .then(function (autoParsedBody) {
        // :)
    });

rpap('http://echojs.com')
    .then(function (autoParsedBody) {
        // =)
    });
```

Comment: @PhillipYS It's part of [ES6 destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Basically `...opt` expands all properties inside `opt` into the object where it is written. `{uri}` is valid ES6 and means the same as `{uri: uri}`. So the processed code would be similar to `request({ transform: function(){...}, uri: uri })`.